# Coinvariant representative of homogeneous space cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

Given a compact homogeneous space $M = K/L$, consider its de Rham complex $(\Omega^*,d)$. Will every cohomology class $[\omega] \in ker(d)/im(d)$ contain a representative $\nu$ which is invariant with respect to the left $K$-action on $\Omega^*$?

Comment: Yes, assuming that $K$ is a connected compact Lie group. Indeed,  $K$ acts on the integral cohomology trivially, because $K$ is connected. Hence $K$ acts trivially on the de Rham cohomology. Furthermore, since $K$ is compact, it preserves a Riemann metric on $M$, hence it acts on harmonic forms, and acts trivially, because it acts trivially on  the de Rham cohomology. Such a harmonic form is the canonical $K$-invariant representative of a cohomology class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming that $K$ is a connected compact Lie group.

Indeed, fix $n$ such that $0\le n\le d={\rm dim}(M)$.
The group $K$ acts on the integral cohomology group $H^n(M,\Bbb Z)$ trivially, because $K$ is connected, while $H^n(M,\Bbb Z)$ is discrete. 
Therefore, $K$ acts trivially on the de Rham cohomology group

$$H^n_{\rm dR}(M,\Bbb R)=H^n(M,\Bbb R)=H^n(M,\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb R.$$

Consider the point $x=e\cdot L\in K/L=M$ with stabilizer $L$.
Then $L$ acts on the tangent space $T_x(M)$. Since $L$ is compact, it preserves a positive definite quadratic form on  $T_x(M)$. It follows that $M$ admits a $K$-invariant Riemannian metric $g$. 
Therefore, $K$ acts on the vector space
${\mathcal H}^n(M,g)$ of harmonic differential $n$-forms on $M$ with respect to $g$.

Since $M$ is compact, by a theorem of Hodge a cohomology class $\xi\in H^n_{\rm dR}(M,\Bbb R)$ is represented by a *unique* harmonic form $\omega\in {\mathcal H}^n(M,g)$; see for instance the book by Jürgen Joost "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis", Theorem 2.2.1. 
Since $K$ acts trivially on $H^n_{\rm dR}(M,\Bbb R)$, it acts trivially on ${\mathcal H}^n(M,g)$. Thus the harmonic differential form $\omega$ is a $K$-invariant representative of $\xi$.

Comment: Why must $K$ act trivially on $H^n(M,\mathbb{Z})$? Is this a general result about discrete sets with an action of a compact connected Lie group?

Comment: Why does this trivial action then extend to the tensor product $H^n(M,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let $G$ be a connected topological group acting continuously on a discrete topological space $X$. Let $x\in X$. Consider the map $$\phi_x\colon G\to X, \quad g\mapsto g\cdot x.$$ The map $\phi_x$ is continuous, hence the image $G\cdot x=\phi_x(G)$ of the *connected* group $G$ is a connected subset of $X$, containing $x$. Since $X$ is discrete, we conclude that $G\cdot x=\{x\}$. Thus $G$ acts on $X$ trivially.

Comment: Concerning $H^n(M,\Bbb R)$: You need some definitions of the functors $H^n(M,\Bbb Z)$ and of $H^n(M,\Bbb R)$. Then you will see immediately that $$H^n(M,\Bbb R)=H^n(M,\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb R$$ and that ${\rm Aut}(M)$ acts on $H^n(M,\Bbb R)$ via the first factor of $H^n(M,\Bbb Z)\otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb R$.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you will not see that immediately, but need some version of the [Universal coefficient theorem](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology).